# I can't understand what they said, please help. "Counting Stars" by copy band three guys

Tags: pronunciation, listening

I studied English with pop songs.
Recently, I like to listen the song "counting stars" by three copy band guys

But I can't understand what they said perfectly after about 3:24.

Somebody help me, please.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cSLAO7zxS2M
["Counting Stars" - OneRepublic (Alex Goot, Kurt Schneider, and Chrissy Costanza Cover)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cSLAO7zxS2M)

[what i can hear that part, not sure with ().]

Look guys, this is Kurt, Chrissy, Alex.
That was "Counting Stars" by "Onerepublic".

Hope you guys liked it, if you (dig the song on itunes, so link of that would be down below.)

And if you guys like this video,
make sure to give it the big thumbs up
and to subscribe (to all of our channels and links of video by right heads)

(That still will.)

Catch ya guys next time.
Bye. Bye.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few differences, but you heard most of it correctly.

"**What up** guys..."

"Hope you guys liked it; **if you did, it's on itunes, a link for that will** be down below."

"subscribe to all of our channels and **the links will be above our heads.**"
 
(The links wound up being below their heads in the actual video...)

"Yes they will."

Comment: But I can't still catch them speaking those words. It's most difficult for me to listen up what the natives speak easy words but very quickly. i appreciate you, again.

Comment: @GoTyosyu You're quite welcome.  I think everyone feels that way when they are first learning a language.  "Why do they talk so fast!?!?"  It gets easier with time.  :-)  In this video, Chrissy was trying to be funny and spoke in a strange voice, so he was not easy for me to understand either, and American English is my first language.

Comment: +1 Just want to add a couple of tiny bits. I think she said, "make sure to give it **a** big thumbs up", and it probably is "subscribe to all our channels" rather than "subscribe to all of our channels".

Comment: Thank you for your adding. I couldn't hear that part clealy, but I thought it as "the" because of "thumbS". I got that is "thumbs-up." Easier English words are more difficult to use. Thank you help me become a little clever.